# Add auth user in django admin interface: HTTP 403 error

Tags: django, apache, django-authentication, http-status-code-403, mod-security

I have a weird issue when I try to save a new user through the admin interface.
I get a `403` HTTP status code error.

I've changed nothing in the auth application.

Here are my middlewares:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'johnny.middleware.LocalStoreClearMiddleware',
    'johnny.middleware.QueryCacheMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
)
```

I've no idea where to look, or either have any idea of what could provocate this. Any clue is welcome.

Comment: Could you publish the full debug info, please?

Comment: It's possible not a Django error. Your user (your webserver) has not rights to read from some directory or file.

Comment: Well, it on the prod server. Even though i've ``DEBUG=True`` I get the standard error without any debug info... I suspect something from an apache module ( the admin certified me that it wasn't mod_security)

Comment: Is there error only if your would like to create a new user? What happens when you delete a user?

Comment: It works when i delete users...

Comment: OK. Can you create new user via command shell (python manage.py shell)?

Comment: User.objects.create_user('john', 'lennon@thebeatles.com', 'johnpassword')

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12258/discussion-between-renard-and-sergzach)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your user probably has not permissions to add new users. It's a normal behaviour to return 403 code in this case. View the doc, please: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.permission_required.

And (in this case) your user *can have* permission to delete users because it's the decoupled permissions.

You can view permissions of the user it: http://yoursite.com/admin/auth/user/{user_id}/ ( from superuser or user that can view permissions of other users).

**Update**. The author of the question found the decision: the situation was because of Apache settings (switching mod_security off fixed the problem). Unfortunately I have not deep knowledge about the module and I can't give more detailed information.

Comment: But I try to add a user with superuser role. So I should be able to do it  anyway.

Comment: Check if superuser flag is checked on the mentioned page.